# RestSharp - Not able to post json using RestSharp if I am reading my json from a file

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am struggling to get this done and have tried various options but not able to post JSON when I read it from a file and pass it in `request.AddJsonBody(jsonBody);`

Note* It works, when i try passing it directly like: `request.AddJsonBody(new { deviceId = "qa" });`

But my requirement is to save request in a file and read it from there and pass it in `request.AddJsonBody(jsonBody);`

AddBody is deprecated, thus I am using AddJsonBody. Reading content from a file and then converting into JsonObject to pass in AddJsonBody doesn't work as it treats it like we have not passed valid json or treat it like an empty json.

```
[TestMethod]
        public void createWithFile()
        {
         static readonly string textFile = @"C:\Users\RequestFiles\Users.txt"; // sample contents of my file : {"deviceId" : "qa"}

            if (File.Exists(textFile))
            {

                text = File.ReadAllText(textFile);

            }
            JObject jsonBody = JObject.Parse(text);
            Console.WriteLine(jsonBody);

            RestClient client = new RestClient("myurl");

            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.AddJsonBody(jsonBody);
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            var response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode.ToString());


        }
```

Comment: Did you check the typical things when reading something from a file and using it elsewhere. Like a.) Encoding b.) Does it contain a BOM c:) What new line character has been used etc.

Comment: @Ralf-  I tried to print after reading a complete file as a string an then before passing it Console.WriteLine(jsonBody) looks fine till there. Please help if you can.

Comment: Does AddJsonBody cope with JObject? I assume RestSharp has a AddBody method where you can just throw in the the text from the file. Actually when you say it does not work you should tell use how it fails. Errormessages etc.

Comment: AddBody is deprecated, thus I am using AddJsonBody. Passing content from file to AddJsonBody doesn't work as it treats it like we have not passed valid json or treat it like empty json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send *any* text as the request body. `AddJsonBody` specifically designed to serialise the object that is given as a parameter to JSON. If you have the JSON string already, just use the `AddParameter` with the `RequestBody` parameter type.

It is clear from the [test code](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/67aae8c0f5dfd4415bc67471327faca148c2c56c/test/RestSharp.IntegrationTests/RequestBodyTests.cs#L101):

```
    [Test]
    public void Can_Be_Added_To_PUT_Request()
    {
        const Method httpMethod = Method.PUT;

        var client  = new RestClient(_server.Url);
        var request = new RestRequest(RequestBodyCapturer.Resource, httpMethod);

        const string contentType = "text/plain";
        const string bodyData    = "abc123 foo bar baz BING!";

        request.AddParameter(contentType, bodyData, ParameterType.RequestBody);

        client.Execute(request);

        AssertHasRequestBody(contentType, bodyData);
    }
```

You need to set the correct content type, of course.